# Android app with client server data share with android

Tags: android, cordova, client-server, android-wireless

I'm trying to build an App with phonegap, made to be available on Android platforms.
Now I would now if it's possible to create an app that, once installed on multiple devices which share the same wireless network, where on one device there is the "server app" and on the other devices, the "client app".
And is possible to made these apps communicate to each other over the local wireless network?
Thanks...

Comment: I think if you wanted the apps to communicate with each other over the local wireless network, you would need some type of server running somewhere to pass messages around. AFAIK there is no way you could have one app "serve" data to the other apps. You could probably do this if you used bluetooth or NFC with two apps (maybe more than two.) Doing this over wifi though will require an actual server somewhere though.

Comment: mdns for the rescue @MBillau

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

(1) Enable the hotspot function on the device running "server app".

(2) Let all other devices connect to this hotspot.

(3) Create a TCP/UDP server on the "server app". The client app then connects to this server to download/upload data. The server may maintain a table recording the IP addresses of all clients. Clients can then request IP addresses of other clients from the server and send data to them directly.

A client gets the IP address of the server in the follow way: it first retrieves its own IP address, for example, 192.168.1.3; then the server IP (the IP address of the device serving as hotspot) is 192.168.1.1. All devices use the same port number and communicate through socket.